# How to translate DAO query into Yii2 ActiveRecord. How to select and use specific columns from joined table

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii2, dao

I am using Yii2 for my project. I need to "translate" this DAO query into ActiveRecord one. Let me first show you my DAO query, and then my try with Active Record, and then I will specify what I am trying to do. I believe that everything will be clear to you, once you see DAO version.

Here is the DAO version:

```
return $db->createCommand("SELECT c.id, c.naziv, c.naziv_bih, c.naziv_hr, c.illustration_url, 
                           coc.cpv_id, COUNT(coc.club_offer_id) AS offersCount, TRIM(TRAILING '0' FROM c.id) AS cpvRoot

                           FROM club_offer_cpv coc 

                           JOIN cpv c ON coc.cpv_id = c.id 

                           JOIN club_offer co ON coc.club_offer_id = co.id

                           JOIN club_territories ct ON co.club_id = ct.club_id 

                           WHERE ct.teritorije_id = $territory_id

                           GROUP BY c.id 

                           ORDER BY offersCount DESC

                           LIMIT 9 ;

                     ")->queryAll();
```

And this is my try with AR:

```
return self::find()->select("cpv_id, COUNT(club_offer_id) AS offersCount, TRIM(TRAILING '0' FROM cpv_id) AS cpvRoot")

                    ->with([
                        'cpv',
                        'clubOffer',
                        'clubOffer.clubTerritories' => function ($query) {
                            $query->andWhere("teritorije_id = $territory_id");
                        },
                    ])
                   ->groupBy(['cpv_id'])
                   ->limit(9)
                   ->orderBy(['offersCount' => SORT_DESC])
                   ->all();
```

1) This query will select * from the cpv table, and I want only specific columns: `c.id, c.naziv, c.naziv_bih, c.naziv_hr, c.illustration_url`.

2) I need to apply this condition `WHERE ct.teritorije_id = $territory_id`. You can see how I tried to write this in AR, but it does not work, if I look at debugger, this conditions is not in query at all.

3) I need to apply GROUP BY and ORDER BY like you see in DAO version.

4) clubOffer is relation with table club_offer, but I am not selecting anything from it, except that I use it in DAO for joining.

5) clubTerritories is relation of club_offer table with club_territories table. I need it for WHERE part of the query.

What I am doing wrong ? Eager loading is giving me better performance, but I do not understand if I can do same things with it like with JOIN. Can you help we with this problem ? I would like to use AR but I'm having a hard time "translating" DAO into AR. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is: `Query->with()` method you are using is not alias for join - you must still use `join()` if you want to filter results by related tables attribute. `with` method only creates extra db requests and populates/adds results as AR relations models. If you still need all your ARs including relations in results you may use `join` for filtering and `with` for attaching relations both.